# How can we use parallel loading in data warehouse ingest scripts to load into multiple tables at the same time without duplications?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-warehouse, data-ingestion

is it possible to load data into multiple tables using `INSERT ALL` without adding duplications or without using `overwrite` to accomplish it?

As `WHEN` clause doesn't support subqueries unless it returns a value to compare with something else, i am currently trying with the following:

```
INSERT ALL
INTO TEMP (PKEY, TITLE) VALUES ( ID, TITLE_NAME )
SELECT
$1 AS ID,
$2 AS TITLE_NAME
FROM @azure_stg/mti_test.csv (FILE_FORMAT=>'CSV')
WHERE $1 NOT IN (SELECT PKEY FROM TEMP)
```

my aim is to add another 3 tables to be filled with data in parallel within the same query without adding duplications. so I tried to add another `into table2 select ...` but it didn't work.

Comment: So the question is: Is it possible to insert into multiple tables in parallel without using the conditional multi-table insert?

Comment: @Marcel and specify only unavailable rows for each table.

Comment: Typically in such situation you have in you input: `table_name` and  `ID`. You should discard all `ID`s  that exists in the corresponding `table`. What do you *expect* to do if you have only list od `ID`s?

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question correct, you want to insert into several tables with one statement and without any condition. Main consideration is: Are all INSERT statements using the same source data or different source data?

If all statements are using the same source data, this is the syntax:

```
insert all
  into t1
  into t1 (c1, c2, c3) values (n2, n1, default)
  into t2 (c1, c2, c3)
  into t2 values (n3, n2, n1)
select n1, n2, n3 from src;
```

See here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/insert-multi-table.html

If the statements are based on different SELECT-statements, you have to split them up into single INSERT statements.

Comment: this works for PIT tables in data vault. i need to load in parallel into tables without duplications.